# Bias of estimator at Uniform Distribution

Tags: uniform-distribution

$\newcommand{\sgn}{\operatorname{sgn}}$Good evening everyone. I might need some help on something. Suppose we have $n$ independent variables from $U[0,1+θ]$ and suppose also that $λ=1+θ$. The estimator of $θ$ is $\bar{θ}=2 \bar{X} - 1$. Ι need to find the bias of $\bar{θ}$ knowing that the  distribution of $\bar{X}$ of $n$ variables, which they are from $U[0,1]$ , is the Bates distribution, which has the following probability density function: $$f(x)=\frac{n}{2(n-1)!} \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}(nx - k)^{(n-1)} \sgn(nx -k)$$

where $\sgn(nx-k) = \begin{cases} -1,\ & \text{if } nx<k, \\ \phantom{-}0, & \text{if } nx=k, \\ \phantom{-}1, &\text{if } nx > k. \end{cases}$

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have $X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim\text{ i.i.d.} \operatorname{Uniform}[0,1+\theta]$ and $\bar X = (X_1+\cdots+X_n)/n.$ If you want the bias of $2\bar X-1$ as an estimator of $\theta,$ you do not need to know much about the distribution of $\bar X.$ You only need its expected value, which can easily be found without knowing much about its distribution. Its expected value can be shown to be the same as that of $X_1,$ as follows:

\begin{align}
& \operatorname E\left( \frac {X_1+\cdots+X_n} n \right) = \frac 1 n \operatorname E(X_1+\cdots+X_n) \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac 1 n\left( \operatorname E(X_1) + \cdots + \operatorname E(X_n) \right) = \frac 1 n \Big( n \operatorname E(X_1)\Big) = \operatorname E(X_1) = \frac{\theta+1} 2.
\end{align}

(Note that $2\bar X -1$ is a lousy estimator, not only because there are others with substantially smaller mean squared errors, but also because in some cases $2\bar X-1$ is smaller than $\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\},$ and you *know* that $\theta$ cannot be smaller than that maximum. The best unbiased estimator is a constant multiple of the aforementioned maximum observed value. There are biased estimators that are also constant multiples of the maximum and that have smaller mean squared errors than the best unbiased estimator.)

Comment: I know that but how can I find an expression of the bias of $\bar{θ}$ based on this distribution of $\bar{X}$ ? And which is the correct probability density function of $\bar{X}$ of n variables from $U[0,1+θ]$ and not from $U[0,1]$ ?

Comment: The density you're looking for is merely a rescaling of the one you called $f(x).$ You're simply multiplying all random variables involved by $\theta+1.$ Thus the density you seek is $$\frac 1 {\theta+1} f\left( \frac x {\theta+1} \right).$$ Sometimes I prefer to express this by saying that one probability distribution is $f(x)\,dx$ and the other is $$f\left( \frac x {\theta+1} \right)\, \frac{dx}{\theta+1}.$$ That makes it clear why the outer division by $\theta+1$ is done. $\qquad$

Comment: So to find the expected value do I have to solve $\int_{1/2}^λ $(2x - 1)$\frac 1 {\theta+1} f\left( \frac x {\theta+1} \right)$ dx ?

Comment: @ManosMikes : If you insist on doing it by using that integral, notice that $$ 
\int_0^\theta (2x-1) f\left( \frac x {\theta+1} \right)\, \frac{dx}{\theta+1} = \int_0^1 (2(\theta+1)u-1) f(u) \, du. $$

Comment: But is the integral that I want to use right or do I have to change something to find its expected value and then its bias? Let me note that λ=1+θ

Comment: I think what you've got is probably the right function but I haven't checked it closely.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I found what I was looking for.